# Power BI, I need a multi-layer map with Drilldown Choropleth... invalid json+not seeing fields to add data

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, geojson, arcgis, powerbi-custom-visuals

Anyone have experience with Drilldown Choropleth *recently*? I have taken a step back to try ArcGIS, but want to have a multi-layer map built in Power BI with shading using this add-in. I am having issues with loading the json- one for States (USA), one for Metro Area (MSA, USA). Also, not seeing the fields to add data points. This info I researched on the app my info has a json file link that is going to a 404.

If anyone wants to provide tips to transfer over to a contained ArcGIS, I would accept that.

More on the app: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104381044?tab=overview

I basically need one layer shading on drill down for geo with points, then add one layer for demographic stats, one layer for population stats. Help?

Answer (score 0):

for topojsons that work:

https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson

I used the US Counties one, so that's all I can comment on working.